# Validate Item Before Submit APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to validate a year field (item) to ensure that the field is 4 digits and fits between 1960 and 2059. I want to do this before I submit the page, preferably after leaving the field through tab or click out. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the settings for numeric items should do this for you (from 5.1). If the submit page is pressed, APEX will do it's best to do any [client side validation](https://explorer.co.uk/client-side-validations/) before submitting.

[image: numeric settings.]

You can create a dynamic action to test the value yourself on change, but you should retain any server side validation.

There are also some plug-ins that can help, such as [Live Validation](https://github.com/nbuytaert1/apex-live-validation).